# Facebook API wall post method fires onComplete for both Post and Cancel?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug in the Facebook API but in my callback for a Facebook wall post the onComplete gets fired regardless of if I press "POST" or if I press "CANCEL".  And I can't provoke the onCancel no matter what I do... has anyone else dealt with this, and if so, what's the work around?

Here's my code...

```
 myApp.facebook.dialog(context, "feed", b, new Facebook.DialogListener() {                      
                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "FBError " + e);                           
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"FBDialog Error " + e);                         
                        }
                        //THIS GETS CALLED NO MATTER WHAT THE USER DOES
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"FB CONFIRM");
                            user.setPostedToFacebook(2);
                            startActivity(new Intent(context, Survey.class));
                            finish();                           
                        }

                                                    //THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"FB CANCEL");
                            user.setPostedToFacebook(1);
                            startActivity(new Intent(context, Survey.class));
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... in the way of an update, facebook has confirmed that it is a bug and has filed it.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/198419313569151